Moment Time zone Africa/Cairo giving me +2 instead of +3
Recently time zone of Egypt time zone is updated to +3 but library still getting +2 time zone. Iam using 2.29.3 version
I tried several libraries but no library is giving me the updated timezone (I sont want t o update libraries, so I didn't try)
